# bestglm R package error using Poisson regression

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to use the bestglm package in R to fit a Poisson regression model. Here is my code:

`bestmodel <- bestglm(Xy, family = poisson, IC ="BIC")`

and the output is

`Morgan-Tatar search since family is non-gaussian.
Error in dimnames(Bestq) <- list(c("BICq1", "BICq2"), c("q1", "q2", "selected k")) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)`

Theres nothing special about the data frame Xy, except that it does not strictly contain integers, which is causing the final collection of warnings. Notably, the code

`bestmodel <- bestglm(Xy, IC ="BIC")`

runs just fine.

Is this a bug, or is there something I can do to get it to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** For technical reasons, you're going to have trouble doing likelihood-based or IC-based model selection for Poisson GLMs with non-integer data (the likelihoods aren't necessarily well-defined).  Working around the problem via quasi-likelihoods is possible: I have a hack at a solution below, but if you value your conclusions you should definitely double-check that the quasi-AIC formula is correct!

I think non-integer values are indeed the problem.  I can reproduce it as follows:

```
library("bestglm")

set.seed(101)
## y must be **LAST** column (not documented clearly!)
Xy <- data.frame(
    x1=rnorm(100),x2=rnorm(100),
    y=rpois(100,2))
```

Make the response variable non-integer:

```
Xy2 <- transform(Xy,y=y+0.5)
```

These all work:

```
bestglm(Xy)
bestglm(Xy,IC="BIC")
bestglm(Xy,IC="BIC", family=poisson)
```

This fails:

```
bestglm(Xy2,IC="BIC", family=poisson)
##  Error in dimnames(Bestq) <- 
## list(c("BICq1", "BICq2"), c("q1", "q2", "selected k")) : 
##    length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

I'm not sure whether this should count as a bug, since Poisson GLMs aren't really intended to handle non-integer data (but I can appreciate that there are sometimes
reasons to do so).  I think the proximal problem *might* be that the BIC (and other information criteria based on the log-likelihood) is infinite, because a non-integer value is technically impossible under a Poisson model, so the likelihood is zero ...

```
BIC(glm(y~1,data=Xy2,family=poisson))
## Inf
```

In principle you could get around this by computing a quasi-likelihood/quasi-AIC, but R's built-in `quasipoisson` family was written by purists who don't believe that such a thing makes sense:

```
BIC(glm(y~1,data=Xy2,family=quasipoisson))
## NA
```

I think the best solution would be to write your own `my_quasipoisson` family that replaces

```
quasipoisson()$aic
function (y, n, mu, wt, dev) 
NA
```

with a sensible quasi-likelihood.

**update**: here's a workaround.  It's a hack at a sensible quasi-AIC expression (which is also used by `BIC()`, I think).  It comes with even less warranty than usual.

```
my_QP <- function(link="log") {
    QP <- quasipoisson(link=link)
    QP$aic <- function (y, n, mu, wt, dev) {
        nobs <- length(y)
        disp <- dev/n
        dev0 <- -2*sum((-mu + y*log(mu) -lfactorial(y))*wt/disp)
        dev0 + 2  ## extra penalty parameter
    }
    QP
}

bestglm(Xy2,family=my_QP)
```

It might make sense to cross-check to see what packages like `MuMIn` and `AICcmodavg` (which as I recall allow quasi-AIC-based model averaging and selection) do ...